# Change input value according which option is selected

Tags: javascript

I want change the value of an `input field` according which option is selected.
I did this function but it doesn't give me any result:

```
<script>

   function changeFunc() {
    var idpn = document.getElementById("idpn").value;       

    if(idpn.startsWith('v531')) {
       if(document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex = 2) {

            var ltvalue =document.getElementById("ltid").value=30;
        } else if (document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex = 3) {

            var ltvalue =document.getElementById("ltid").value=30;
         }

    } 
        alert('ok');
}

  </script>
```

Can you please tell where's the error in my function.

Comment: Use == or === instead of = in if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the **2 wrong** comparisons (`=` to `==`) in the **`if`** statements the code work fine.

I also combined the `if/else` statements, and placed the value of `document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex` into a variable to make it more readable.

```js
function changeFunc() {
  var idpn = document.getElementById("idpn").value;

  if (idpn.startsWith('v531')) {
    var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex;

    //both values are in 1 'if statement' with an or operator
    if (selectedIndex == 2 || selectedIndex == 3) {
      var ltvalue = document.getElementById("ltid").value = 30;
    }
  }
  alert('ok');
}
```

```html
price_type_chosen:
<select id="price_type_chosen">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>idpn:</label><input id="idpn" type="text" value="v531" />
<br>
<label>ltid:</label><input id="ltid" type="text" value="" />
<br><br>
<button onclick="changeFunc()">changeFunc</button>
```

Choosing options 2 OR 3 puts value of 30 in `#ltid`

Answer (score 1):

you are not comparing , you are assigning value

```
if(document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex = 2)
```

Comment: I changed it but always the same result do not change the value 30.

Comment: can you log the value document.getElementById("ltid").value and check once whether it is going in if condition or not,

Comment: it return the value existing in DB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` in your comparisons.

```
<script>

       function changeFunc() {
        var idpn = document.getElementById("idpn").value;       

        if(idpn.startsWith('v531')) {
           if(document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex == 2) {

                var ltvalue =document.getElementById("ltid").value=30;
            } else if (document.getElementById("price_type_chosen").options.selectedIndex == 3) {

                var ltvalue =document.getElementById("ltid").value=30;
             }

        } 
            alert('ok');
    }

      </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still the same result

Comment: I can't do this one I should define what's the ltvalue.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the if statement is satisfied?

Comment: Change the value ltvalue  to 30.

Comment: I don't know I asked the question